# Quantum Scalar i80 - I see the tape drive, but not changer

Tags: linux, backup, centos6, tape, tapedrive

I have a Quantum Scalar i80 connected via SAS to a CentOS 6 server. When I look in /proc/scsi/scsi, I see the tape drive, but I don't see the changer.

From /proc/scsi/scsi:

```
Host: scsi8 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: IBM      Model: ULTRIUM-HH6      Rev: E6R7
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
```

In /dev, I see nst0, nst0a, nst0l, and nst0m (and also the st0 variants.) I don't see anything that appears to be a changer. Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: What does the Control Path configuration in the i80 Setup menu show?

Comment: The i80 has 2 drives. The tapes are divided into 2 partitions. In the Control path, one partitions is assigned to one drive, and the other partition to the other drive. One drive is cabled up to the server in question. The other drive is cabled up to a Windows server.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an ancient post , but the changer will be accessed by an 'sg' device , ie scsi generic. If you are running Linux , it will already have sg support.

sg provides a lower level interface to SCSI devices than st. st is for scsi tapes.

you need to install the `mtx` command line tool as well to control the media changer device.

sg devices for the tape drives will be created as well

system messages will show the devices , with a type '1' being a tape device , a type '8' being a media changer , a type '0' being a disk ...

see sg2 , is type 8 and it's a 'ch' ....

```
[    6.145348] st 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 1
[    6.145449] st 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 1
[    6.145542] ch 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 8
[    6.145696] st 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 1
[    6.146526] st 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 1
[   43.891764] scsi 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[   43.898283] scsi 7:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[   43.908209] sd 7:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[   43.918352] sd 7:0:3:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
[   43.930734] sd 7:1:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
```